# term filter on "bool must", not returning any results

Tags: elasticsearch

I had a query which was performing as expected on a few dozen records.   We've started feeding more data into our ES instance and now I am not getting any results back:

First query:

```
{
  "query": {
   "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "match": {
            "message": "new connection attempt failed: null"
           }
        }
      ] 
    }
  }
}
```

I get a number of records back.  This shows the records are actually in my index as I expect.

If I pick one of the records from the result:

```
 {
        "_index": "logstash-2018.04.12",
        "_type": "log",
        "_id": "AWK3J1xarbUl8ovcY8uv",
        "_score": 6.621839,
        "_source": {
          "cluster": "dev-east-1-c5",
          "offset": 35858135,
          "level": "ERROR",
         ...
      }
```

and then add a term filter to only get the entries for a specific cluster,  I get nothing back  (but only when the index gets loaded up with more than a couple thousand records).

```
 {
   "query": {
     "bool": {
       "must": [
         {
           "match": {
            "message": "new connection attempt failed: null"
           }
         }
      ],
       "filter": [
       {
         "term": {
           "cluster": "dev-east-1-c5"
         }
         }
      ]
    }
 }
   }
```

To describe in plain English what I am trying to do:

message --  match any entry which contains the message string

then filter those to only return entries where the clustername is an exact match.

---

Edit 4/12/18 --  Adding mapping for log type as requested

```
{  
   "logstash-2018.04.12":{  
      "mappings":{  
     "log":{  
        "_all":{  
           "enabled":true,
           "norms":false
        },
        "dynamic_templates":[  
           {  
              "message_field":{  
                 "path_match":"message",
                 "match_mapping_type":"string",
                 "mapping":{  
                    "norms":false,
                    "type":"text"
                 }
              }
           },
           {  
              "string_fields":{  
                 "match":"*",
                 "match_mapping_type":"string",
                 "mapping":{  
                    "fields":{  
                       "keyword":{  
                          "ignore_above":256,
                          "type":"keyword"
                       }
                    },
                    "norms":false,
                    "type":"text"
                 }
              }
           }
        ],
        "properties":{  
           "@timestamp":{  
              "type":"date",
              "include_in_all":false
           },
           "@version":{  
              "type":"keyword",
              "include_in_all":false
           },
           "application_name":{  
              "type":"text",
              "norms":false,
              "fields":{  
                 "keyword":{  
                    "type":"keyword",
                    "ignore_above":256
                 }
              }
           },
           "application_version":{  
              "type":"text",
              "norms":false,
              "fields":{  
                 "keyword":{  
                    "type":"keyword",
                    "ignore_above":256
                 }
              }
           },
           "beat":{  
              "properties":{  
                 "hostname":{  
                    "type":"text",
                    "norms":false,
                    "fields":{  
                       "keyword":{  
                          "type":"keyword",
                          "ignore_above":256
                       }
                    }
                 },
                 "name":{  
                    "type":"text",
                    "norms":false,
                    "fields":{  
                       "keyword":{  
                          "type":"keyword",
                          "ignore_above":256
                       }
                    }
                 },
                 "version":{  
                    "type":"text",
                    "norms":false,
                    "fields":{  
                       "keyword":{  
                          "type":"keyword",
                          "ignore_above":256
                       }
                    }
                 }
              }
           },
           "cluster":{  
              "type":"text",
              "norms":false,
              "fields":{  
                 "keyword":{  
                    "type":"keyword",
                    "ignore_above":256
                 }
              }
           },
           "geoip":{  
              "dynamic":"true",
              "properties":{  
                 "ip":{  
                    "type":"ip"
                 },
                 "latitude":{  
                    "type":"half_float"
                 },
                 "location":{  
                    "type":"geo_point"
                 },
                 "longitude":{  
                    "type":"half_float"
                 }
              }
           },
           "host":{  
              "type":"text",
              "norms":false,
              "fields":{  
                 "keyword":{  
                    "type":"keyword",
                    "ignore_above":256
                 }
              }
           },
           "input_type":{  
              "type":"text",
              "norms":false,
              "fields":{  
                 "keyword":{  
                    "type":"keyword",
                    "ignore_above":256
                 }
              }
           },
           "level":{  
              "type":"text",
              "norms":false,
              "fields":{  
                 "keyword":{  
                    "type":"keyword",
                    "ignore_above":256
                 }
              }
           },
           "level_value":{  
              "type":"long"
           },
           "logger_name":{  
              "type":"text",
              "norms":false,
              "fields":{  
                 "keyword":{  
                    "type":"keyword",
                    "ignore_above":256
                 }
              }
           },
           "message":{  
              "type":"text",
              "norms":false
           },
           "offset":{  
              "type":"long"
           },
           "source":{  
              "type":"text",
              "norms":false,
              "fields":{  
                 "keyword":{  
                    "type":"keyword",
                    "ignore_above":256
                 }
              }
           },
           "tags":{  
              "type":"text",
              "norms":false,
              "fields":{  
                 "keyword":{  
                    "type":"keyword",
                    "ignore_above":256
                 }
              }
           },
           "thread_name":{  
              "type":"text",
              "norms":false,
              "fields":{  
                 "keyword":{  
                    "type":"keyword",
                    "ignore_above":256
                 }
              }
           },
           "type":{  
              "type":"text",
              "norms":false,
              "fields":{  
                 "keyword":{  
                    "type":"keyword",
                    "ignore_above":256
                 }
                }
             }
          }
       }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: What you want is a post_filter, see the docs here https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.2/search-request-post-filter.html

Comment: Interesting...  I hoisted the filter out and put it after the query as a post_filter.    Still getting 0 hits.    Does this look syntactically correct?  It runs fine: {
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "match": {
            "message": "new connection attempt failed: null"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "post_filter": {
    "term": {
      "cluster": "dev-east-1-c5"
    }
  }
}

Comment: Take the match query out of bool clause, it is unnecessary

Comment: I don't get you guys, his query is perfectly valid. No need for `post_filter` or take the `match` out of the bool query. First the `filter` is applied to shrink the document set on which to apply the match clause. @JvmSd121 can you show your mapping please?

Comment: I added the mapping in above in the main post.  I found some documentation showing where I could force the field as unanalyzed for exact matches.   The problem is we are not likely to always want to only do exact matches on the the cluster and host field.

Comment: I changed the term filter from cluster to cluster.keyword.   From my reading, this seems to be the right approach for "not_analyzed" post-2.x.   I'm on 5.6.        Now all my results are for the proper cluster but they definitely don't all have matching message fields (by my definition where every record contains a match for the exact substring).     I think once I properly tweak the bool must,  I should be getting expected outcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There were two issues:

The first issue was mentioned in my comment.  By doing a term filter on plain "cluster" and not "cluster.keyword" an analyzer was tweaking things and I was not getting hits on exact matches.  (this appears to be the approach in post 2.x)

The second issue was on the bool match for message.   match has no notion of position and was giving all sorts of unexpected results for large data sets.   The fix  was to change the bool match to a bool match_phrase and then update the filter according.

It *seems* to be working as I want now.  I am somewhat concerned there may be a more performant way to do this.  I saw some people were using wildcards and I believe this is a slight improvement over that.  Not sure if there is a guru approach of which I am not aware.